# I want to resolve the issue "js:includer-bmf (trj)"

Tags: javascript, web, virus

I want to resolve the virus issue "js:includer-bmf (trj)" for my website. 
It only comes on PC where Avast antivirus is installed. When i open my website on my PC, "js:includer-bmf (trj)" threat appearing by Avast.
I have searched a lot but could not find any authentic solution.
Can any one tell me, how to resolve this issue? Because my customers are facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Run a webscan on https://sucuri.net/ it will show you what files have got infected scripts then fix those scripts.

Or run a antivirus on you server if its a dedicated or a VPS server.

Comment: That link seems to be spam

Comment: Its not a spam, its a service provider which can tell the site is infected or not